# How to fetch data using useQuery after previous queries done

Tags: reactjs, react-query

i use react-query to fetch some data ,and i  need to call `fetchPagesContent` function in `useQuery` after `fetchlangs` function is done, because i need dynamic  ID of lang to use it in `fetchPagesContent` function how i can dow that with react-query

```
import React, { createContext,useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import { useQuery } from 'react-query'
        
const fetchPagesContent = async () => {
  const resp = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/content-pages/lang_id=1');
  return resp.json();
}
    
const fetchlangs = async () => {
  const resp = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/languages');
  return resp.json();
}
          
export const AppContext = createContext();
        
export default function AppContextProvider({children}) {
  const resp = useQuery('langs',fetchlangs );
  const resp = useQuery('page',fetchPagesContent);
  
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={resp}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Something else: There shouldn't be the need to pass data from react-query down the component tree via Context. I mean you can, but the idea is more to call `useQuery` with the same key (best abstracted in a custom hook) wherever you need your data

Answer (score 4):

you are looking for [dependent queries](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/dependent-queries), where you disable the second query via the `enabled` option for as long as you have no data for the first query:

```
const langs = useQuery('langs',fetchlangs );
const resp = useQuery('page',fetchPagesContent, { enabled: Boolean(langs.data) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative solution, you can use third-party [useAsyncEffect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-async-effect2) hook to make requests or any other async things inside your component with cancelable async effects ([Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-async-effect-several-requests-hb54l?file=/src/TestComponent.js)):

```
import React from "react";
import { useAsyncEffect } from "use-async-effect2";
import cpFetch from "cp-fetch/lib/native";
/*
 Note: the related network request will also be aborted
 Check out your network console
 */

function* fetchAPI(url) {
  const response = yield cpFetch(url);
  // you can use a native fetch directly, but cpFetch wrapper will abort
  // the request automatically when the async effect canceling
  return yield response.json();
}

function TestComponent(props) {
  const [cancel, done, result, err] = useAsyncEffect(
    function* () {
      this.timeout(props.timeout);
      // we use mocky-delay=2s to slowdown the response for demo purpose
      const data = yield* fetchAPI(
        "https://run.mocky.io/v3/39486170-1983-457b-a89f-b0736ccf7961?mocky-delay=2s"
      );
      return yield* fetchAPI(
        `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/${data.fetchId}`
      );
    },
    { states: true }
  );

  return (
    <div className="component">
      <div className="caption">useAsyncEffect demo:</div>
      <div>
        {done
          ? err
            ? err.toString()
            : JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)
          : "loading..."}
      </div>
      <button className="btn btn-warning" onClick={cancel} disabled={done}>
        Cancel async effect
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```